# How are asynchoronous problems handled with imperative programming?

Tags: architecture, asynchronous-programming, imperative-programming

## Context

To level set, I've been working with OOP and FP for my whole career, so my experience with the imperative paradigm is limited. The team I joined is made up of very senior (20+ years xp) imperative programmers using a domain specific language - think Pascal. The team is challenged to try new things (*not the focus of this question*). I've been tasked to architect a system for an asynchronous problem.

## Question

Currently, the team uses something to the equivalent of `Thread.Sleep` to handle the asynchronous bits, but that leads to all sorts of bugs.

From what I gather, since imperative programming works using step-by-step instructions, it appears that polling is probably the main way of solving asynchronous problems. **In general, what are the other techniques used to solve asynchronous problems using an imperative paradigm?**

## Attempts

I introduced the team other tools like callbacks, promises and events in the hopes that I can change the language, but unfortunately, they found it overwhelming. I'd like to build a system that plays to the team's strengths, but slowly nudges them in the direction to change how they approach asynchronous problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that your DSL has the required low-level primitives (mutexes, semaphores, an efficient [`select`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/select.2.html)-like API etc), you can in theory implement almost anything you like; some incredibly efficient asynchronous programs have been written in C since time immemorial with nothing more than those constructs.

However, the reason that people moved away from these low-level constructs towards higher-level constructs (callback, promises, the actor model or whatever else) is not because you can't write this kind of program with those low-level constructs, but because **it is notoriously hard to write correct programs with those low-level constructs**.

I would strongly recommend that you get your team to use those higher level constructs, even if they find it overwhelming today. If your team don't want to/can't learn new skills, that's a different issue and one you probably have to discuss with your management.